# How can I show $a_n = \cos \left(\frac{1}{2n} \right)- \cos \left(\frac{1}{2n+1} \right)$ implies $a_{n+1}<a_n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

If $a_n = \cos \left(\frac{1}{2n} \right)- \cos \left(\frac{1}{2n+1} \right)$ for natural numbers $n$, then $a_{n+1}<a_n$.

I tried to differentiate and show that it is smaller than $0$, but a more complicated sine function comes out.

How can I show this inequality?

Comment: The claim is false: $a_n$ is a negative sequence that converges to $0$, therefore it cannot be decreasing.

Comment: But infinite series of (-1)^n *a_n converges. It should be decreasing.

Comment: It is not a matter of being persuasive. It's a matter of speaking the truth.

Comment: Oh... I really apologize to you.. I confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function

$$\cos(x)-\cos\left(\frac x{x+1}\right)$$

which evaluates to $a_n$ at $x=\dfrac1{2n}$.

This function is decreasing around zero (as a function of $x$) and $a_{n+1}>a_n$.

---

The derivative is

$$-\sin(x)+\frac1{(x+1)^2}\sin\left(\frac x{x+1}\right)\sim-3x^2.$$